# getting content size of scrollView prior to viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm using a `UIScrollView` instance in a story board and I'm trying to set the `contentOffse`t of my scroll view as a ratio of it's height. I can do this in `viewDidAppea`r, the only method in the `viewController` lifecycle were the `scrollView.contentSize` property is available. My problem with this is that it has a negative effect on my transition animation. Ideally I'd like to set my `contentOffset` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillAppear`, but without access to the `scrollView.contentSize.height` I can't set that based on ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling `setNeedsLayout` and then `layoutIfNeeded` prior to `viewDidAppear`. That will create the frames and the `contentSize` should be available.